# When did template template parameters become part of the standard?

Tags: c++, templates, template-templates

I understand from Section 1.5.2 of **Modern C++ Design** that template template parameters were not widely supported by compilers at the time of the book's writing. When did this feature become part of the standard?

Comment: Well there is [N1081](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/1997/N1081.pdf) from 1997, which proposes to **remove** template template-parameters, and [N0607](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/1995/N0607.pdf) from 1995 which mentions them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely since the first standard, C++98. It is in C++03 **14.3.3 Template template arguments**, and I doubt such a large change would have been introduced in what is essentially a revision of C++98. The same section is present in copies of the C++98 standard, although I cannot vouch for their authenticity. The ISO standard document itself has been withdrawn.